# Twitter api - POST statuses/filter with OAuth

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

Now i use this code to get stream from twitter, and it works fine.
But soon the basic auth with user and password will be deprecated, how can I send this request using oauth?

```
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://stream.twitter.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
            if (!$fp)
            {
                echo "ERROR: Twitter Stream Error: failed to open socket";
            } else
            {


                $request  = "GET /1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=";
                $request .= urlencode(implode($_keywords, ',')) . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
                $request .= "Host: stream.twitter.com\r\n";
                $request .= "Authorization: Basic ";
                $request .= base64_encode($this->m_username . ':' . $this->m_password);
                $request .= "\r\n\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like tmhOAuth to achieve something like this easily enough.

Find the lib here: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

An example using filter.json:
https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth-examples/blob/master/streaming.php

Also you'll require an App, signup/signin (using your normal twitter account) and create one via : https://dev.twitter.com